# Can I use the same option elements in multiple select drop downs?

Tags: html, select, dropdown

I'm trying to find a way to use the same list of options for multiple select drop downs in a table. I have to use the same drop down 15 times for a form but I don't want the code to have the same big statement repeated 15 times in the code:

```html
<select id="RangeDD" style="border: 0px; outline: 0px; width: 100%">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
  <option value="VeryLow">Very Low</option>
  <option value="Low">Low</option>
  <option value="LowAverage">Low Average</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="HighAverage">High Average</option>
  <option value="Superior">Superior</option>
  <option value="VerySuperior">Very Superior</option>
  <option value="NotAdministered">Not Administered</option>
</select>
```

If there is a way to do this without using JavaScript that would be preferred. The site I'm building in has JavaScript stored in a different area and will not let me simply put `<script>` tags in my code.

Comment: No, there isn't. Why can't you add elements to your code?

Comment: Not possible without some kind of programming language that can manipulate the HTML. Is there a server side language running the site that you are able to use?

Comment: sadly no, not possible. There is a template tag, but its best controlled via Javascript, that would help you out.

Comment: im not sure if it is a bug, but trying to save the html with a <script> in the html gives me a warning in the site saying
"There are JavaScript blocks in the HTML format that should be moved to the JavaScript field."

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a virtual include statement, if your site allows it.

Create a document called options.html, with just the code for the options in it:

```
<option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
<option value="VeryLow">Very Low</option>
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="LowAverage">Low Average</option>
<option value="Average">Average</option>
<option value="HighAverage">High Average</option>
<option value="Superior">Superior</option>
<option value="VerySuperior">Very Superior</option>
<option value="NotAdministered">Not Administered</option>
```

Then add the include statement to your main page wherever you want the select drop-down to appear:

```
<select id="RangeDD" style="border: 0px; outline: 0px; width: 100%">
   <!--#include virtual="options.html"-->
</select>
```